# 2001 Toyota Tacoma collects rain water in bed

Tags: toyota, truck, tacoma, water

My 2001 Toyota Tacoma is normally parked slightly downhill. Since it has a plastic bed liner with no drain holes, the rain water collects near the front and I end up with a koi pond. Doing some internet research, most people suggest either parking in reverse (not practical in my case), just living with the rain water and let it empty when you drive down the road (I would prefer not to do this), or just drilling your own drain holes.

The problem with drilling the holes through the liner is that it creates a path for water to collect underneath the bed liner and rust out the bed.

Is there any novel solution to allow the bed to drain, and keep things free from rust? I was thinking of trying to install some setup very similar to a kitchen sink drain: Some drain flange with a waterproof sealant underneath which drains straight through to the ground. That would require me to drill through both the bed liner and the real bed.

Comment: Drill a couple small holes in the bed as well, then cover the freshly cut holes with some body matching paint.